# Smoother Effect transition once clicked on responsive menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have developed a responsive menu and once resized it collapses to a box with menu on it. Including a piece of JS i doen that once the user click on it it goes down. I want to have a smoother transition when the user clicks on menu. Can anyone suggest me amendments :

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#down").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("open")){
            $(this).removeClass("open");
        }else{
            $(this).addClass("open");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/g7zQw/

Answer (score 0):

The most used,the most loved the unique and only.
JQuery fade effect.

Heres how your JS should look like :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#down").click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("open")){
                $(this).removeClass("open");
                $("#cssmenu").fadeOut("slow");
    }else{
                $("#cssmenu").fadeIn("slow");
                $(this).addClass("open");
            }
        });

});
```

Let me know if this is what you want.
Find more on : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_effects.asp